# Setting variable as a field reference in a DAO.Recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code;

```
Dim tbloutput As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim v As String
Set tbloutput = dbLocal.OpenRecordset("tbl_temp_forecast")

For i = 38 To 52
v = CStr(i)
.Cells(Rowindex, Columnindex).Value = tbloutput![v]
Columnindex = Columnindex + 1
v = ""
Next
```

The issue I have is when i try reference tbloutput![COLUMN NAME] I want to use the value of v or i but a simple tbloutput![i] or tbloutput![v] doesn't work.

Could you advise on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small correction in your code .

Dim tbloutput As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim v As String
Set tbloutput = dbLocal.OpenRecordset("tbl_temp_forecast")

```
For i = 38 To 52
  v = CStr(i)
  .Cells(Rowindex, Columnindex).Value = "tbloutput![" & v & "]"
  Columnindex = Columnindex + 1
  v = ""
Next
```

Let me know if this works...